# why does my background disappear when i start a new activity?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-intent

Good morning guys I was having problems with Androids out of memory error because my app uses a lot of images. So i found code on the  web that creates a class that stores the image as a variable for each activity and then replaces the image stored in the last activity with the image of the new activity. The image being replaced is the background of each activity and the problem I am having is as i click the button to start the new activity the last activities background disappears like 2 seconds before the last activity screen disappears and the new activity starts so it looks terrible and not smooth to the user. I want the background and the activity to disappear at the same time before the new activity starts so it looks smooth. Here is the code for the class that changes the background.

```
public class MyApp extends Application {
   private RelativeLayout bgimg; // layout of the activity
   private Bitmap background; // background in the Bitmap format
   private BitmapDrawable bg; // background in the Drawable format

   public void loadBackground(int id) {
       background = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getResources().openRawResource(id));
       bg = new BitmapDrawable(background);
       bgimg.setBackgroundDrawable(bg);
    }
    public void unloadBackground() {
       if (bgimg != null)
       bgimg.setBackgroundDrawable(null);
       if (bg!= null) {
          background.recycle();
       }
       bg = null;
    }


        public void setBackground(RelativeLayout i, int sourceid) {
               unloadBackground();
               bgimg = i;
               loadBackground(sourceid);
            }


}
```

here is the code for the first activity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {


   private MyApp app;
    private int bgid = R.drawable.main; // id of the background drawable
   private int layoutid = R.id.mainmain; // id of the activity layout
   private RelativeLayout layout; // the layout of the activity

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
      Button startButton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        startButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        app = (MyApp)getApplication();
        layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainmain);
        app.setBackground(layout, bgid); // free last background, and store new one

}

 @Override
   protected void onResume() {
      super.onResume();
      layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(layoutid);
      app.setBackground(layout, bgid);
   }

@Override
public void onClick(View v){
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Intent myintent = new Intent(this,Second.class);
    startActivity(myintent);

}

    }
```

and here is the code for the second activity

```
public class Second extends Activity implements OnClickListener  {
   private MyApp app;
    private int bgid = R.drawable.two; // id of the background drawable
   private int layoutid = R.id.seconds; // id of the activity layout
   private RelativeLayout layout; // the layout of the activity
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.second);
      Button startButton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
        startButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        app = (MyApp)getApplication();
        layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.seconds);
        app.setBackground(layout, bgid); // free last background, and store new one


}
 @Override
   protected void onResume() {
      super.onResume();
      layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(layoutid);
      app.setBackground(layout, bgid);
   }

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Intent myintent = new Intent(this,Third.class);
    startActivity(myintent);



}
```

}

So can someone help me alter my code so that my main activities background does not disappear before my main activities content when I click the button to start a new activity, so making both background and activity content disappear at the same time before the next activity starts?

errors

12-02 11:13:57.588: E/AndroidRuntime(1861): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-02 11:13:57.588: E/AndroidRuntime(1861): java.lang.RuntimeException: Canvas: trying to use a recycled bitmap android.graphics.Bitmap@4063cd38
12-02 11:13:57.588: E/AndroidRuntime(1861):     at android.graphics.Canvas.throwIfRecycled(Canvas.java:1012)
12-02 11:13:57.588: E/AndroidRuntime(1861):     at android.graphics.Canvas.drawBitmap(Canvas.java:1116)
12-02 11:13:57.588: E/AndroidRuntime(1861):     at android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable.draw(BitmapDrawable.java:335)
12-02 11:13:57.588: E/AndroidRuntime(1861):     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:9264)
12-02 11:13:57.588: E/AndroidRuntime(1861):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2584)
12-02 11:13:57.588: E/AndroidRuntime(1861):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2189)
12-02 11:13:57.588: E/AndroidRuntime(1861):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2582)
12-02 11:13:57.588: E/AndroidRuntime(1861):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2189)
12-02 11:13:57.588: E/AndroidRuntime(1861):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2582)
12-02 11:13:57.588: E/AndroidRuntime(1861):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2189)
12-02 11:13:57.588: E/AndroidRuntime(1861):     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:9282)
12-02 11:13:57.588: E/AndroidRuntime(1861):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:419)
12-02 11:13:57.588: E/AndroidRuntime(1861):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.draw(PhoneWindow.java:1924)
12-02 11:13:57.588: E/AndroidRuntime(1861):     at android.view.ViewRoot.draw(ViewRoot.java:1666)
12-02 11:13:57.588: E/AndroidRuntime(1861):     at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:1381)
12-02 11:13:57.588: E/AndroidRuntime(1861):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:2003)
12-02 11:13:57.588: E/AndroidRuntime(1861):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-02 11:13:57.588: E/AndroidRuntime(1861):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
12-02 11:13:57.588: E/AndroidRuntime(1861):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4025)
12-02 11:13:57.588: E/AndroidRuntime(1861):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-02 11:13:57.588: E/AndroidRuntime(1861):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
12-02 11:13:57.588: E/AndroidRuntime(1861):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
12-02 11:13:57.588: E/AndroidRuntime(1861):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
12-02 11:13:57.588: E/AndroidRuntime(1861):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: you do image process in your `Application` class !!! thats horrible

Answer (score 1):

First: I don't recommend using background images, for the sake of performance and supporting the endless screen resolutions.

Second: you can just set the background of each activity root layout container to your image like this:

```
android:background="@drawable/your_bg"
```

sometimes if the background image resolution is too high, the system does not render it.
so you'll need to use multiple versions of your image to support the different screen densities or use a 9-patch to scale with different resolutions.

Comment: Image resolution is too high, totes!

Answer (score 0):

Try following:

1. Just have following code in onCreate() only, remove it from onResume as this will be called after onCreate and will lead to unloading and loading.

   layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(layoutid);
         app.setBackground(layout, bgid);
2. Instead of set the drawable to null in unloading method and then loading new image in loading combine the two steps, i.e. instead of setting background to null directly replace it will new one...and ofcourse set the original bitmap of previous activity to null and also call the recycle

I hope this steps help

Comment: thanks prashant but for step two i am confused so in my unload method do it like this   bgimg.setBackgroundDrawable(bg);

Comment: Something like this public void replaceBackground(int id) {
       if (bgimg == null){
  return ;
       }
       
       Bitmap newBackground = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getResources().openRawResource(id));
       BitmapDrawable newBg = new BitmapDrawable(background);
       bgimg.setBackgroundDrawable(newBg);

       if (bg!= null) {
          background.recycle();
       }
       bg = null;

       background =newBackground;
       bg = newBg;
    }

Comment: prashant I have implemented your code and replaced both load background and unload background with your code replace background but i am getting no background on the first activity and then an error "trying to use a recycled bitmap" on the second activity. do you know what i have done wrong

Comment: sorry...I forget to correct one line in my code...BitmapDrawable newBg = new BitmapDrawable(background); Here still background is used. Replace this with BitmapDrawable newBg = new BitmapDrawable(newBackground);

Comment: The first activity now loads up with a background but still getting the same error when the second activity loads up about trying to use a recycled bitmap. Just to make sure iv done this right this is how i have coded my setBackground method public void setBackground(RelativeLayout i, int sourceid) {
     
       bgimg = i;
     
       replaceBackground(sourceid);
    }

Comment: ok replace if (bg!= null)  with if (bg!= null && !background.isRecycled() ) this should avoid recycled exception.

Comment: Can you pleae share the exact stack trace of the exception and also point out the exact line where it is happening

Comment: sorry prashant i will paste it below my question

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42324/discussion-between-user2608169-and-prashant-thakkar)

Comment: on closely looking at your code it looks like you are using 2 different layout for both the Activity....in that case you can set background in xml file directly using background attribute for the RelativeLayout

Comment: can't do that as i am using different backgrounds for all my activities so the further down the activities i go by using backgrounds directly set up in xml i get an out of memory error so thats why this method was more preferable